# Multiple Checkboxes

Tags: php, html, forms, email, checkbox

Found this on the internet. How can I put this output into an email?
Normally I use

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_body = "$name";
```

I would like the output of this code into my $email_body.
Is this posible?

```js
<?php
  $aDoor = $_POST['formDoor'];
  if(empty($aDoor)) 
  {
    echo("You didn't select any buildings.");
  } 
  else 
  {
    $N = count($aDoor);

    echo("You selected $N door(s): ");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
      echo($aDoor[$i] . " ");
    }
  }
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <body>
   <form action="test.php" method="post">

    Which buildings do you want access to?<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="A" />Acorn Building<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="B" />Brown Hall<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="C" />Carnegie Complex<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="D" />Drake Commons<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value="E" />Elliot House

    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />

  </form>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_body ='';

<?php
  $aDoor = $_POST['formDoor'];
  if(empty($aDoor)) 
  {
    $email_body = "You didn't select any buildings.";
  } 
  else 
  {
    $N = count($aDoor);

    $email_body .= "You selected $N door(s): ";
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
    $email_body .=  $aDoor[$i] . " ";
    }
  }
?>
```