# Extracting data from a form that has a list with multiple values

Tags: php, jquery, html, email

thanks for you all to took a moment and review my code, unfortunately I was unable to solve it until I review more codes and re-did everything so I was able to find the solution via PHP for the form:

My form in html (some descriptions are in spanish, sorry for that):

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
    <select class="mdl-textfield__input" name="contactMarca" id="contactMarca">
        <option value="Selecciona">Selecciona</option>
        <option value="Acura">Acura</option>
        <option value="AlfaRomeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
        <option value="AstonMartin">Aston Martin</option>
        <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
<label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="contactMarca"> Marca</label><br><br>
</div>
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
    <select class="mdl-textfield__input" name="contactVersion" id="contactVersion">
       <option value="Selecciona">Selecciona</option>
       <option value="Acura" data-value="ACURA ILX A-SPEC 4P L4 2.0L ABS BA QC AC GPS R18 AUT., 05 OCUP.">ACURA ILX A-SPEC 4P L4 2.0L ABS BA QC AC GPS R18 AUT., 05 OCUP.</option>
       <option value="Acura" data-value="ACURA RL AUT., 05 OCUP.">ACURA RL AUT., 05 OCUP.</option>
       <option value="Acura" data-value="ACURA RLX 4P V6 3.5L SPORTSHIFT AUT., 05 OCUP.">ACURA RLX 4P V6 3.5L SPORTSHIFT AUT., 05 OCUP.</option>
       <option value="Acura" data-value="ACURA TL AUT., 05 OCUP.">ACURA TL AUT., 05 OCUP.</option>
       <option value="Acura" data-value="ACURA TL V6 3.7L SPORTSHIFT R-18 AUT., 05 OCUP.">ACURA TL V6 3.7L SPORTSHIFT R-18 AUT., 05 OCUP.</option>

<button type="submit"  id="submit"><span>Enviar </span> <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></button>
```

Basically everything woks fine, the email sends the information but it doesn't  send the data from "data-value"

This is my PHP:

```
<?php

    $site_owners_email = 'mail@master.com'; // Replace this with your own email address
    $site_owners_name = 'Page'; // replace with your name

    $name = filter_var($_POST['contactName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_var($_POST['contactEmail'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $subject = filter_var($_POST['contactSubject'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $codigo = filter_var($_POST['contactCopo'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $phone = filter_var($_POST['contactPhone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $model = filter_var($_POST['contactModel'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $marca = filter_var($_POST['contactMarca'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $version = filter_var($_POST['contactVersion'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $confirm = filter_var($_POST['contactConfirm'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $uso = filter_var($_POST['contactUso'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $error = "";

    if (strlen($name) < 2) {
        $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
    }

    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
        $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address";
    }

    if (strlen($subject) < 2) {
        $error['subject'] = "Please enter a subject.";
    }

    if (strlen($codigo) < 2) {
        $error['codigo'] = "Please enter your Code.";
    }

    if (strlen($phone) < 2) {
        $error['phone'] = "Please enter your phone.";
    }

    if (strlen($confirm) < 6) {
        $error['version'] = "Por favor introduce tu Versión.";
    }

    if (!$error) {

        require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->AddAddress($site_owners_email, $site_owners_name);
        $mail->IsHTML(true);

        $mail->From = $email;
        $mail->FromName = $name;
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = '<b>Nombre del Asegurado:</b> '. $name .'<br/><b>E-mail:</b> '. $email . '<br/><b>Codigo Postal:</b> '. $codigo . '<br/><b>Telefono:</b> '. $phone . '<br/><b>Modelo:</b> '. $model . '<br/><b>Marca:</b> '. $marca . '<br/><b>Version:</b> '. $confirm . '<br/><b>Tipo de Uso:</b><br/>' . $uso;

        $mail->Send();

        echo $theResults = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!--=============== basic  ===============-->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Grupo Integral de Seguros | Cotizacion Autos</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="Seguros"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Cotizacion Autos, A donde vayas estamos contigo."/>
        <meta property="og:title" content="Grupo Integral de Seguros | Cotizacion Autos"/>
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://giseguros.com.mx/images/LogoGIlarge-01.png"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://giseguros.com.mx/"/>
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
        <meta name="twitter:site" content="@" />
        <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@" />
        <!--=============== css  ===============--> 
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugins.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <!--=============== favicons ===============-->
        <!-- Standard Favicon--> 
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://giseguros.com.mx/favicon-196x196.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="http://giseguros.com.mx/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="http://giseguros.com.mx/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://giseguros.com.mx/favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196" />
    </head>
    <body>
HTML to make prettier the result that email has been sent.
    </body>
</html>
EOD;
echo "$theResults";

    } # end if no error
    else {

        $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? "<div class='alert alert-danger'  role='alert'>" . $error['name'] . "</div> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? "<div class='alert alert-danger'  role='alert'>" . $error['email'] . "</div> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['subject'])) ? "<div class='alert alert-danger'  role='alert'>" . $error['subject'] . "</div> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? "<div class='alert alert-danger'  role='alert'>" . $error['message'] . "</div>" : null;

        echo $response;
    } # end if there was an error sending

?>
```

So I'm sorry if is a lot of data but I want to know how could I just extract the "data-value" because it just extract the value and it gives me the brand from the cars and I need the description from my form in my PHP without screw it in this php that now works perfectly besides of that data value issue?

Comment: You're constantly overwriting your email content when you do `$e_content =`. You need to concatenate the text like `$e_content .=`

Comment: Thanks I already change that was helpful when the email is sent, it gives me all the information mentioned `$e_body = "Name $name" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "E-mail: $email\r\nTelefono: $tel";
$e_content = "Message:\r\n$comments\r\nModel: $model\r\nBrand: $brand\r\nVersion: $version\r\nCP: $zip\r\nType: $type" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;` it just that the problem persist, it doesnt give me the values from the select list in the form, what else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting values in $_POST then all is good just change the below lines on your code

```
$e_content = "Message:\r\n$comments" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content .= "Modelo:\r\n$model" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content .= "Marca:\r\n$brand" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content .= "version:\r\n$version" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content .= "CP:\r\n$zip" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content .= "Uso:\r\n$type" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
```

when you do $e_content = 'Some Value', you are creating a new variable and assigning a new value to it, In your case you want all the information to be sent so you will have to append other values to already created variable

Comment: Hello, thanks I already edit it and worked, is just that is still not working the select options in the form, what else i can do?
this was the change:

`$e_body = "Name $name" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL; 
$e_reply = "E-mail: $email\r\nTel: $tel"; 
$e_content = "Message:\r\n$comments\r\nModel: $model\r\nBrand: $brand\r\nVersion: $version\r\nCP: $zip\r\nType: $type" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;`

Answer (score 0):

```
     <select class="mdl-textfield__input" name="contactVersion" id="contactVersion">
           <option value="Selecciona">Selecciona</option>
           <option value="ACURA ILX A-SPEC 4P L4 2.0L ABS BA QC AC GPS R18 AUT., 05 OCUP." data-value="ACURA ILX A-SPEC 4P L4 2.0L ABS BA QC AC GPS R18 AUT., 05 OCUP.">ACURA ILX A-SPEC 4P L4 2.0L ABS BA QC AC GPS R18 AUT., 05 OCUP.</option>
           <option value="ACURA RL AUT., 05 OCUP." data-value="ACURA RL AUT., 05 OCUP.">ACURA RL AUT., 05 OCUP.</option>
           <option value="ACURA RLX 4P V6 3.5L SPORTSHIFT AUT., 05 OCUP." data-value="ACURA RLX 4P V6 3.5L SPORTSHIFT AUT., 05 OCUP.">ACURA RLX 4P V6 3.5L SPORTSHIFT AUT., 05 OCUP.</option>
           <option value="ACURA TL AUT., 05 OCUP." data-value="ACURA TL AUT., 05 OCUP.">ACURA TL AUT., 05 OCUP.</option>
           <option value="ACURA TL V6 3.7L SPORTSHIFT R-18 AUT., 05 OCUP." data-value="ACURA TL V6 3.7L SPORTSHIFT R-18 AUT., 05 OCUP.">ACURA TL V6 3.7L SPORTSHIFT R-18 AUT., 05 OCUP.</option>

</select>
```

You didnt close the `</select>`

Why are you giving the same value of all the options?

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Dawud, I had to keep the Javascript because the form contains over 100 options, I tried your option also and the php is still not posting the information from telephone, model, version and type, it corrects the data thanks to your way to put `$e_content.` what else could be happening? Perhaps is the post method or has to be something in the form?

Comment: @Jivanz i have added some section. Please you can try and give me ur feed back but i tried the same code it works fine for me here. you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510682/multiple-checkboxes/45516342#45516342

Comment: Hi Dawud, Thanks again, I dont know why is still not working for me, I appreciate your time to help me to find a solution on this, is still something in the php that doesn't recognise the list and take the data value to add it to the mail in the php, not even the telephone number works, however the name and the email works fine, what else could be? Perharps is the method when is posted

Comment: Hey Dawud, can you check this again? I fixed but I just couldn't find a solution to add the other value "data-value" to my email, everything is perfect but in the mail just get sent the value from the brand instead of the data that describes the cars

Comment: @Jivanz check the my answer

Comment: I give the value"brand" to filter the data of the brand for the cars, when they select a brand it filters the descriptions of the cars for each brand, so I added data-value to give the real value for each car description but in the php just get selected the same value of the brand non taking the data value, that is my issue now

Comment: @Jivanz you mean each brand has it own version?